# iOS Today widget auto height

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget

I'm loading text data from xml to my today widget label so height can't be static. Since font size is 17px I counted that there are max 30 characters in one line, and by that I tried to set height like this

```
int number_of_characters = [self.string length];
[label sizeToFit];
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, (number_of_characters/30)*22+40);
```

I add +40 to height because I have static text on top of widget, and multiple by 22 since font size is 17px I assumed that there's 5px spaceing between two lines.

But this doesn't work, I can't figure why :( . Is there some other way to make widget height dynamic?

Comment: First describe how this is not working.

Comment: The height is to big/ to small, sometimes I got 20px extra and sometimes 20px less

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
You send him the 'stirng', 'width' and the font.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForValue:(NSString *)value andWidth:(CGFloat)width andFont:(UIFont *)font{

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [value boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 999.0f)
                                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                    attributes:attributesDictionary
                                       context:nil];
    //    CGSize size = [value sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 99999.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat result = frame.size.height;
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
CGFloat height = [self heightForValue:@"This is example code." andWidth:250];
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. It shouls be in the implementation.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get how I set preferredContentSize

Comment: Copy my method in your .m file and change your function  (number_of_characters/30)*22+40   with [self heightForValue:self.string andWidth:self.view.frame.size.width]

Comment: After changing as you said I'm getting this error "Property 'string' not found on object of type' TodayViewController' "
Pointing at this ->
 [self heightForValue:self. **string** andWidth:self.view.frame.size.width]

Comment: No visible @interface for 'TodayViewController' declares the selector 'heightForValue:andWidth:'

**and I put your code in**  implementation TodayViewController

Comment: Tnx for your help, but I got it working with my code by setting line spacing.